# Privacy settings in photo object, using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

How I can change privacy settings in photo object, when I use Graph API and create new photo in my album? How can I do it in my Android application?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no decisions for that. 
Till present moment - fb API not gives this possibility.